# Can we detect what function to call on fly from parameters given at runtime?

Tags: c++

Say we have `N` function overrites, we receive argunments array, parsed it into some types (say first time we get `int`, `string`, `string`; second time we get `int`, `int`, `int`); Now we want to call for first set of arguments our `call(int, string, string)` while second time `call(int, int, int)`. Can we detect which function to call on fly having arguments types array?

Comment: What do you mean by 'parse the arguments array'? Are you receiving a string which you are trying to convert into ints and substrings?

Comment: That is what function templates is for. How over, operations done in the functions must be supported by the instantiated types. But templates is a compile time concept though. I don't understand the term "arguments types array".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do type choice in *C++* at runtime. That is because *C++* is one of the [Strongly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing) languages.

You could do something similar to what you are suggesting in e.g. Python -- where variables are happy to change their type during runtime.

You can do something close -- but not quite the same, with inherited and derived classes. If you have a superclass, you could have a "factory" function that returns a pointer to a superclass (containing a diff object depending on some input). Now if all the objects have the desired functionality implemented, you could call a function on the pointer. E.g.:

```
class Base{
    virtual void functionality();
};

class Squirrel : public Base{
    void functionality() {
        std::cout << "I love hazelnuts!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Box : public Base{
    void functionality() {
        std::cout << "Stuff can be put in here!" << std::endl;
    }
};


Base *factoryMethod(std::string someInput){
     if (someInput == "1")
         return new Squirrel();
     else
         return new Box();
}

int main(void){
    std::cin >> input;
    Base *object = factoryMethod(input);
    object->functionality();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you've just parsed a load of text, established the types of the entries in that text and run a load of if statements and depatched the arguments appropriately. But who knows what the OP was trying to do!

Comment: @Rook but even then, you can't have a function `if (arg_is_int) return (int)(value); else return (string)value;`. All types are predetermined at compile time!

Comment: `vector<argtypes> atypes = parse(args); if (atypes[0] == argtypes::string && atypes[1] == argtypes::int) despatch_fun(string(args[0]), convert_arg<int>(args[1]));` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write anoverloaded member function with the relevant params?

If you are receiving an unknown number of arguments and want to call the correct functions based upon them then you will need to some additional work.  Perhaps have an enum as the first parameter which implies a parameter set e.g.:

```
enum eParamList
{
    eParamList_START,
    IntIntInt,          // following data is 3 ints
    IntIntChar,         // following data is int, int, bool (only joking its a char)
    eParamList_ENDS
}
```

Or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the low tech way of doing it. I don't know exactly what you mean by argument types array, but let's assume you are given some kind of vector called `args`, and you can determine if an element is a number or not, and convert the element into a number or string. Then, you can implement a loop like this one:

```
std::string s[3];
int n[3];
unsigned mask = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); ++i) {
    if (is_number(args[i])) {
        mask |= (1U << i);
        n[i] = get_number(args[i]);
    } else {
        s[i] = get_string(args[i]);
    }
}
```

And then, switch on the mask:

```
switch (mask) {
case 0x01: call(n[0], s[1], s[2]); break;
case 0x07: call(n[0], n[1], n[2]); break;
default:
    std::cout << "unhandled combination: " << mask << std::endl;
    break;
}
```